# Make Ubuntu fonts sharper

Tags: fonts

In the last two months I'm trying to do a complete transition from Windows 7 to Ubuntu.

There is something that is really missing. I really like the sharp and think fonts in windows (I'm not talking about the font type  - 'Arial','Consolas' atc.).

I think that the Ubuntu fonts looks better, but after several hours I feel like my eyes are really tired.

BTW - I have the same problem with the Apple computer at work too (MacBook pro).

Is it a theme issue? Can i change it by configuration?
Can you recommend a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Font rendering is really a personal-preference (or, often, a ‘what I'm used to’) thing. Since you like Windows' font rendering, [How can I make fonts look like they do in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-like-they-do-in-windows/955#955) is the question you want to be looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer of following questions and see if it helps.
[How can I make Ubuntu/GNOME look better i.e more smaller and compact?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23523/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-gnome-look-better-i-e-more-smaller-and-compact)
The accepted answer and DPI settings in answer by @Musnoon did the trick for me.

Also look at the accepted answer to the following question.
https://superuser.com/questions/19824/better-ubuntu-fonts/35192#35192

Answer (score 0):

Download and install MyUnity from Ubuntu Software Center.

Go to the Fonts section and from here you can edit fonts.